# Return Max record in subquery and bring it into my main query

Tags: sql

I have need to display the MAX rate for each Schedule and Pay Grade from my sub query and add it to my main query. The select statement for my subquery is as follows:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE,  MAX(FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_RATE) as MaxRate
 FROM   FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2 FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2
 WHERE  FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.R_STATUS in (5,2)
 GROUP By FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE) MAXRate
 ON MAXRate.SCHEDULE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.SCHEDULE
 AND MAXRate.PAY_GRADE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.PAY_GRADE
```

The query executes separately as well as when I add this to my main query, But when I try to pull the max rate into my main query, I am using MAXRate.PAY_RATE as "MAX Rate". I get error message "Invalid column name 'PAY_RATE'."

Thought? Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you post the entire query? You have aliased it as `MAXRate.MaxRate`

Comment: Did not see any wrong with your sub query

Comment: The Join does not have a column `Pay_Rate`. It has `MaxRate`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? The answer is different, so you have to get the tags right.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that, its SQL-Server, will see how I can fix that.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice you have aliased it saying `MAX(FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_RATE) as MaxRate` and then trying with a different column name `PAY_RATE` and thus the error. Change your subquery part to be like below. Also to avoid confusion, don't alias column and inline view with same name. Now you can access the said column saying `XXX.MaxRate`

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE,  MAX(FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_RATE) as MaxRate
 FROM   FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2 FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2
 WHERE  FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.R_STATUS in (5,2)
 GROUP By FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE) XXX
 ON XXX.SCHEDULE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.SCHEDULE
 AND XXX.PAY_GRADE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.PAY_GRADE
```

Comment: Yes I wondered that too and did what you recommend first. I still swapped my subquery out with yours, changed my select statement in my main to just XXX.PAY_RATE. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use with Ties and row_number function to return a dirived table of just the max Rates

```
     (SELECT top 1 with ties FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE, FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_RATE
       FROM   FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2 FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2
       WHERE  FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.R_STATUS in (5,2)
       ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.SCHEDULE,FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_GRADE order by  FV_PRSAGDTL_VW2.PAY_RATE desc)) as MaxRate
  ON MAXRate.SCHEDULE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.SCHEDULE
  AND MAXRate.PAY_GRADE = HR_EMP_POSITIONS.PAY_GRADE
```

Comment: Doesn't this need an Over by clause somewhere? Tried this as is and I get the following error message: The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause. Forgive me, I'm a SQL newbie

Comment: sorry , fast typing.  Edited

Answer (score 0):

The Join does not have a column Pay_Rate. It has MaxRate. – WEI_DBA 21 mins ago

This was the correct answer. Thanks for that catch!